# Saving multiple outputs of foreach dopar loop

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I would like to know if/how it would be possible to return multiple outputs as part of `foreach dopar` loop.

Let's take a very simplistic example. Let's suppose I would like to do 2 operations as part of the `foreach` loop, and would like to return or save the results of both operations for each value of `i`.

For only one output to return, it would be as simple as:

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
cl <- makeCluster(3)
registerDoParallel(cl)

oper1 <- foreach(i=1:100000) %dopar% {
    i+2
}
```

`oper1` would be a list with 100000 elements, each element is the result of the operation `i+2` for each value of i.

Suppose now I would like to return or save the results of two different operations separately, e.g. `i+2` and `i+3`. I tried the following:

```
oper1 = list()
oper2 <- foreach(i=1:100000) %dopar% {
    oper1[[i]] = i+2
    return(i+3)
}
```

hoping that the results of `i+2` will be saved in the list `oper1`, and that the results of the second operation `i+3` will be returned by `foreach`. However, nothing gets populated in the list `oper1`! In this case, only the result of `i+3` gets returned from the loop.

Is there any way of returning or saving both outputs in two separate lists?

Comment: Why not simply `return(c(i+2,i+3))`? If you really need them in separate lists, you can do that after `foreach` returns.

Comment: This is a very simplistic example. In my practical(real) example, the results of the two operations are of different structures (matrix and vector) or (list and scalar). This won't work then..

Comment: That would have been useful to mention in your question... in that case, use `return(list(i+2,i+3))`.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Don't try to use side-effects with foreach or any other parallel program package. Instead, return all of the values from the body of the foreach loop in a list.  If you  want your final result to be a list of two lists rather than a list of 100,000 lists, then specify a combine function that transposes the results:

```
comb <- function(x, ...) {
  lapply(seq_along(x),
    function(i) c(x[[i]], lapply(list(...), function(y) y[[i]])))
}

oper <- foreach(i=1:10, .combine='comb', .multicombine=TRUE,
                .init=list(list(), list())) %dopar% {
  list(i+2, i+3)
}

oper1 <- oper[[1]]
oper2 <- oper[[2]]
```

Note that this combine function requires the use of the `.init` argument to set the value of `x` for the first invocation of the combine function.

Comment: Huge +1 on this one. Took me a long time to figure out the `.init=list()` piece. Doesn't work so well without that!

Comment: The answer does not explain how it would function in general in scenarios of data.frames, matrices or vectors

Answer (score 12):

I prefer to use a class to hold multiple results for a %dopar% loop.

This example spins up 3 cores, calculates multiple results on each core, then returns the list of results to the calling thread.

Tested under `RStudio`, `Windows 10`, and `R v3.3.2`.

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

# Create class which holds multiple results for each loop iteration.
# Each loop iteration populates two properties: $result1 and $result2.
# For a great tutorial on S3 classes, see: 
# http://www.cyclismo.org/tutorial/R/s3Classes.html#creating-an-s3-class
multiResultClass <- function(result1=NULL,result2=NULL)
{
  me <- list(
    result1 = result1,
    result2 = result2
  )

  ## Set the name for the class
  class(me) <- append(class(me),"multiResultClass")
  return(me)
}

cl <- makeCluster(3)
registerDoParallel(cl)
oper <- foreach(i=1:10) %dopar% {
   result <- multiResultClass()
   result$result1 <- i+1
   result$result2 <- i+2
   return(result)
}
stopCluster(cl)

oper1 <- oper[[1]]$result1
oper2 <- oper[[1]]$result2
```

Answer (score 3):

This toy example shows how to return multiple results from a %dopar% loop.

This example:

- Spins up 3 cores.
- Renders a graph on each core.
- Returns the graph and an attached message.
- Prints the graphs and it's attached message out.

I found this really useful to speed up using [Rmarkdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/) to print 1,800 graphs into a PDF document.

Tested under `Windows 10`, `RStudio`, and `R v3.3.2`.

R code:

```
# Demo of returning multiple results from a %dopar% loop.
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
library(ggplot2)

cl <- makeCluster(3)
registerDoParallel(cl)

# Create class which holds multiple results for each loop iteration.
# Each loop iteration populates two properties: $resultPlot and $resultMessage.
# For a great tutorial on S3 classes, see: 
# http://www.cyclismo.org/tutorial/R/s3Classes.html#creating-an-s3-class
plotAndMessage <- function(resultPlot=NULL,resultMessage="?")
{
  me <- list(
    resultPlot = resultPlot,
    resultMessage = resultMessage
  )

  # Set the name for the class
  class(me) <- append(class(me),"plotAndMessage")
  return(me)
}

oper <- foreach(i=1:5, .packages=c("ggplot2")) %dopar% {

  x <- c(i:(i+2))
  y <- c(i:(i+2))
  df <- data.frame(x,y)
  p <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y))
  p <- p + geom_point()

  message <- paste("Hello, world! i=",i,"\n",sep="")

  result <- plotAndMessage()
  result$resultPlot <- p
  result$resultMessage <- message
  return(result)
}

# Print resultant plots and messages. Despite running on multiple cores,
# 'foreach' guarantees that the plots arrive back in the original order.
foreach(i=1:5) %do% {
  # Print message attached to plot.
  cat(oper[[i]]$resultMessage)
  # Print plot.
  print(oper[[i]]$resultPlot)
}

stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: This solution worked really well for me. I did change the last `foreach` loop to a regular `for` loop because it wasn't playing nice with my R Notebook.