# R foreach parallel loop value not saved

Tags: r, domc, doparallel

When executing the following dummy code:

```
P = 2
library(foreach)
library(doMC)
registerDoMC(P)      
f = double(length = P)

print('=== f values in loop ===')
foreach(c = 1:P) %dopar% 
{
    f[c] = c
    print(f[c])
}

print('### f values after loop ###')
for(c in 1:P){ print(f[c])  }
```

I receive the following output:

```
"=== f values in loop ==="
1
2
"### f values after loop ###"
0
0
```

Why are the `f` values assigned in the `foreach` loop not saved?

In particular, why are `f[1]` and `f[2]` equal to zero after the `foreach` loop?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two problems in your code:

1. You haven't assigned the result of the `foreach()` to an object.
2. The `foreach` function doesn't return a value. (Strictly speaking, the function returns the value of `print()` which is NULL.)

Use

```
f <- foreach(c = 1:P) %dopar% { c }
```

The important difference between `for()` in base R and `foreach()` is that anything you do inside `for()` is available in the parent environment of `for()`. However, `foreach()` is a function and anything inside the `foreach()` function is local to the function environment.

In a sense, `foreach()` is more similar to `lapply()` than to `for()`.

Comment: Thanks Andrie, that worked out! Just one follow up question, how to assign two arguments (e.g. f and g) as output from foreach()? I am quite new to R.

Comment: Nevermind, found it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791609/saving-multiple-outputs-of-foreach-dopar-loop