# run a for loop in parallel in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, parallel-foreach

I have a for loop that is something like this:

```
for (i=1:150000) {
   tempMatrix = {}
   tempMatrix = functionThatDoesSomething() #calling a function
   finalMatrix =  cbind(finalMatrix, tempMatrix)

}
```

Could you tell me how to make this parallel ?

I tried this based on an example online, but am not sure if the syntax is correct. It also didn't increase the speed much.

```
finalMatrix = foreach(i=1:150000, .combine=cbind) %dopar%  {
   tempMatrix = {}
   tempMatrix = functionThatDoesSomething() #calling a function

   cbind(finalMatrix, tempMatrix)

}
```

Comment: Running things in parallel requires quite a bit of overhead. You will only get a substantial speed up if `functionThatDoesSomething` takes enough time for the overhead to be worth it.

Comment: I think there's also a lot more work that you need to do before this post is qualified. Look up `parallel` and `doParallel` packages, for instance...

Comment: You shouldn't need this -- `cbind(finalMatrix, tempMatrix)` -- if you are using the `.combine` argument, just return the function output.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Thanks for your feedback. I did look up `parallel` after I posted this question.

Finally after a few tries, I got it running. I have added the code below in case it is useful to others

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

#setup parallel backend to use many processors
cores=detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(cores[1]-1) #not to overload your computer
registerDoParallel(cl)

finalMatrix <- foreach(i=1:150000, .combine=cbind) %dopar% {
   tempMatrix = functionThatDoesSomething() #calling a function
   #do other things if you want

   tempMatrix #Equivalent to finalMatrix = cbind(finalMatrix, tempMatrix)
}
#stop cluster
stopCluster(cl)
```

Note - I must add a note that if the user allocates too many processes, then user may get this error: `Error in serialize(data, node$con) : error writing to connection`

Note - If `.combine` in the `foreach` statement is `rbind` , then the final object returned would have been created by appending output of each loop row-wise.

Hope this is useful for folks trying out parallel processing in R for the first time like me.

References:
http://www.r-bloggers.com/parallel-r-loops-for-windows-and-linux/
https://beckmw.wordpress.com/2014/01/21/a-brief-foray-into-parallel-processing-with-r/

Comment: Can I return multiple different objects from parallel loop. For example I want to return dataframe and vector/list?

Comment: @user1700890, this might reply your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791609/saving-multiple-outputs-of-foreach-dopar-loop

Comment: Note that if your code within the %dopar% loop contains any functions from outside packages, you'll have to put the library() call *inside* the loop.

Comment: @mikoontz This can also be accomplished with the `.packages` argument to `foreach`, e.g. `foreach(i=1:150000, .combine=cbind, .packages=c("dplyr", "tidyr")) ...`

Comment: For optimization purposes, be sure to try compare `detectCores()` VS `detectCores(logical = FALSE)`. If you utilize all your processors for 97% or more, most of the time, your program will most like run faster with `detectCores(logical = FALSE)` otherwise use `detectCores()`