# How to do parallelization for one-line code in R?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am now dealing with large matrix data and want to accelerate the speed. At first I think parallelization may be a good solution, but then I was told that parallelization for a single call is not possible.

Here is an example,When I try the following code, the speed is not increased as the CPU occupation of the desktop remains around 30%, which is the normal value. So, my question is how to accelerate the calculation speed for just one-line code in R?

```
set.seed(1234)
mydata=rnorm(5000*150)
mydata=matrix(mydata,ncol=150)

library(parallel)
cl.cores <- detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(cl.cores)
clusterSetRNGStream(cl,iseed=1234)
clusterExport(cl,"mydata")
clusterEvalQ(cl,library(NbClust))
nc = clusterApply(cl,2,function(min.nc) fun=NbClust(mydata,min.nc=min.nc,max.nc = 8,method = "kmeans"))
stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: You can not parallelize a single call to a function on all your data. You  can parallelize when you have several calls (ie if you can split your data)

Comment: So you mean parallelization for a single call is not possible?

Comment: Exactly, parallelizing means splitting the work to be done on several cpu, which is not possible if you can't split neither the code or the data

Comment: Thank you for your help. But why can a parallel loop work  in R? Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38318139/run-a-for-loop-in-parallel-in-r

Comment: A loop is n calls of a function

Comment: Haha, I see it. So, is there any way to accelerate my code? Thanks a lot.

Comment: googling "cran parallel k-means cluster" gives several options, but I don't know if there's an easy way to put this together with the clustering statistics that `NbClust` gives you ...

Comment: Thanks. I know how to do parallel k-means. The problem is how to accelerate `nc = NbClust(mydata,min.nc=2,max.nc = 8,method = "kmeans"))`.