# How can I run a for loop in parallel in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

Suppose I have a function `f()` and a vector `d`

```
f <- function(x) dexp(x, 2)
d <- runif(10, 1, 5)
```

Now I want to perform a for loop like

```
dnew <- numeric(length(d))
for (i in seq_along(dnew)){
   dnew[i] <- f(d[i])
}
```

. How can I do this in parallel?

Comment: "How to ... Parallel" should likely start with https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html. I think many have had great luck with the `foreach` package, others find `future` to be great, too.

Comment: foreach package did not help me. It took more time if I used foreach

Comment: Okay. If `foreach` used correctly does not speed it up, then (1) start-up costs do not offset parallel execution; (2) you did it wrong or it could be done better; or (3) something else we don't know. In general, for parallelization to work well, the calculation time has to be significantly more than the start-up cost (fork R if appropriate, load libraries, transfer data, etc). If you include your `foreach` code, perhaps somebody adept at that package can help improve its performance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [run a for loop in parallel in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38318139/run-a-for-loop-in-parallel-in-r)

Answer (score 4):

- The example code is faster without for loop:

  ```
  dnew2 <- f(d)          # 'f()' and 'd' from question
  all.equal(dnew, dnew2) # 'dnew' from question 
  [1] TRUE

  library(microbenchmark)
  microbenchmark('for loop' = for (i in seq_along(dnew)){ dnew[i] <- f(d[i]) },
                 'vectorized' = { dnew2 = f(d) })
  Unit: microseconds
         expr    min      lq     mean  median     uq    max neval
     for loop 15.639 16.4455 17.66640 17.0045 18.089 43.938   100
   vectorized  1.249  1.3140  1.44039  1.3845  1.516  2.424   100
  ```
- It can be parallelized with **foreach**:

  ```
  library(foreach)
  library(doParallel); registerDoParallel(2)
  dnew3 <- foreach(i=seq_along(dnew), .combine=c) %dopar% {
      f(d[i])
  }
  all.equal(dnew, dnew3)
  [1] TRUE
  ```

  The paralleized version is slower, because the parallel overhead is larger than the benefit.

  ```
  microbenchmark('for loop' = for (i in seq_along(dnew)){ dnew[i] <- f(d[i]) },
                 'foreach' = { dnew3 <- foreach(i=seq_along(dnew), .combine=c) %dopar% {
                                        f(d[i]) } 
                              })
  Unit: microseconds
       expr       min        lq        mean     median         uq       max neval
   for loop    17.799    22.048    31.01027    32.7615    37.0945    67.265   100
    foreach 11875.845 13003.558 13576.64759 13427.1015 14041.3455 17782.638   100
  ```
- If `f()` takes more time to be evaluated, the **foreach** version is faster:

  ```
  f <- function(x){
      Sys.sleep(.3)
      dexp(x, 2)
  }
  microbenchmark('for loop' = for (i in seq_along(dnew)){ dnew[i] <- f(d[i]) },
                 'foreach' = {dnew3 <- foreach(i=seq_along(dnew), .combine=c) %dopar% {
                                       f(d[i]) }
                  }, times=2)
  Unit: seconds
       expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
   for loop 3.004271 3.004271 3.004554 3.004554 3.004837 3.004837     2
    foreach 1.515458 1.515458 1.515602 1.515602 1.515746 1.515746     2
  ```

Comment: You should combine foreach and your vectorized function (separate in ncores blocks).

Answer (score 1):

Simple for loop

```
a <- function(x) {dexp(x,2)}
d<- runif(10,1,5)
d
dnew < - numeric(length(d))
for (i in 1: length(dnew)){
dnew[i]<- a(d[i])
}
dnew
```

Parallel version

```
library(doParallel)
dnew < - numeric(length(d))
no_cores <- detectCores() - 1  
registerDoParallel(cores=no_cores)  
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores, type="FORK")  
dnew <- clusterApply(cl=cl, x=d, fun = a)  
stopCluster(cl) 
dnew
```

Take a look to this blog's post: https://www.r-bloggers.com/lets-be-faster-and-more-parallel-in-r-with-doparallel-package/

Hope it helps!

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer. As an answer, it should contain at least an adaptation for the OP's data/code. Links-only tend to go stale when the link dies (although admittedly r-bloggers is fairly good at longevity so far).