# Faster way to generate multiple adjacency matrix

Tags: r, igraph, rcpp, rcpparmadillo

Suppose I have a arbitrary probability matrix `P` like below,

```
P = matrix(c(0.3,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.3,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.3),3,3)
P 
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  0.3  0.2  0.2
[2,]  0.2  0.3  0.2
[3,]  0.2  0.2  0.3
```

For single adjacency matrix, it is generated like (unweighted, no self-loof)

```
tem = matrix(runif(3^2), nrow = 3)
tmpG = 1 * (tmpmat < P)
tmpG[lower.tri(tmpG)] <- 0
tmpG <- t(tmpG) + tmpG - diag(diag(tmpG))
```

However, what if I need to generate 100 adjacency matrix, so I write down the following code

```
G = list()
for (i in 1:rep) {
  tmpmat = matrix(runif(n^2), nrow = n)
  tmpG = 1 * (tmpmat < P)
  tmpG[lower.tri(tmpG)] <- 0
  tmpG <- t(tmpG) + tmpG - diag(diag(tmpG))
  if (noloop) {
    diag(tmpG) = 0
  }
  G[[i]] = tmpG
}
```

In my case, the `n >10000` and `T = 1000`, so it is extremely slow, any better idea to improve this?

Comment: The code as written (plus lines for noloop=FALSE, rep <- 100, and n<-3) runs almost instantly on my machine. Are your matrices larger than 3x3 in real life? Using `replicate` will be your friend here to avoid the [Second Circle of the R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)

Comment: In my case, the n > 10000, T = 1000. thanks

Comment: Little typo in your example, you have `tem` where I think you mean `tmpmat`? Also, can you please clarify, when you say `n > 10000`, is that the dimension that you are currently using `3`? And when you say `T = 1000`, is that the number of replications, where you are currently using (the undefined) `rep`?

Comment: Dubukay is right that `replicate(rep, {<<code inside your for loop>>})` will be faster, but by the time your matrices get big it probably won't matter. I don't think you'll get much speed without improving your algorithm. Maybe you could work on only operating the upper triangle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we can do a bit better by only working with a vector of the length needed, and putting it into a matrix at the very end. I haven't checked this very carefully, and your code has no comments for me to compare intention to, so do make sure this is right before trusting it.

```
p_vec = P[upper.tri(P, diag = !noloop)]
nn = length(p_vec)

tmpG_vec = runif(nn) < p_vec
tmpG = matrix(0, n, n)
tmpG[upper.tri(tmpG, diag = !noloop)] = tmpG_vec
tmpG[lower.tri(tmpG, diag = !noloop)] = tmpG_vec
tmpG
```

We can then wrap that in `replicate` for the iteration.

Benchmarking on more dimensions/higher reps, we get about a 25% speedup, but it's still pretty slow (I aborted a benchmark of `n = 5000` because I got tired of waiting). You can probably get quite a bit of speed by running in parallel - say an almost 8x speedup if you have 8 cores. See, e.g., [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38318139/903061), though there may be more modern ways to do it.

```
rep = 5L
n = 2000
noloop = TRUE

P = matrix(runif(n^2), n)
P = P %*% t(P)
P = P / colSums(P)

p_vec = P[upper.tri(P, diag = !noloop)]
nn = length(p_vec)


microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  loop = {
    G = list()
    for (i in 1:rep) {
      tmpmat = matrix(runif(n^2), nrow = n)
      tmpG = 1 * (tmpmat < P)
      tmpG[lower.tri(tmpG)] <- 0
      tmpG <- t(tmpG) + tmpG - diag(diag(tmpG))
      if (noloop) {
        diag(tmpG) = 0
      }
      G[[i]] = tmpG
    }
  },
  diagonal = replicate(rep, {
    tmpG_vec = runif(nn) < p_vec
    tmpG = matrix(0, n, n)
    tmpG[upper.tri(tmpG, diag = !noloop)] = tmpG_vec
    tmpG[lower.tri(tmpG, diag = !noloop)] = tmpG_vec
    tmpG
  }),
  times = 5L
)

# Unit: seconds
#      expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#      loop 1.525028 1.614544 2.136637 2.148771 2.387423 3.007417     5
#  diagonal 1.312022 1.360457 1.592914 1.444902 1.602536 2.244652     5
```