# Foreach combine output - specific vectors

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I am just getting started with `foreach` & `parallel` and encountered some challenges with combining my outputs from each iteration.

Currently, in each iteration, I am outputting a set of variables that I would like to combine into a vector, so that I can obtain some summary stats for across all iterations. 
An example:

```
foreach (s = 1:num) %dopar%{
var1 = ...
var2 = ...
var3 = ...}
```

Ultimately I'd like 3 vectors containing each iteration's produced output, so:
var1 = c(var1 from s=1, var1 from s=2, var1 from s=3, ...)

I looked into the .combine option and attempted to create a function that would append, but found no success.

Comment: What did your attempt look like? How did it fail? It's easier to help with a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). If you need to return more than one value per loop, you'll need to do so in a `list()`

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791609/saving-multiple-outputs-of-foreach-dopar-loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving multiple outputs of foreach dopar loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791609/saving-multiple-outputs-of-foreach-dopar-loop)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `{}` after `foreach...%dopar%` behaves like a function, that is, it will return a value whether you explicitly specify it or not. It is generally not specified but by specifying you can return whatever value you like

```
foreach(I=1:3) %dopar% { <complicated stuff> 
                         return(1) }

# [[1]]
# [1] 1

# [[2]]
# [1] 1

# [[3]]
# [1] 1
```

In your case, you want to return 3 vectors, unfortunately this is not possible

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
registerDoParallel(cl)

foreach(I=1:8) %dopar% { v1 <- "ant"
                 v2 <- "pant"
                 return(v1, v2) }
```

Which results in the following error

```
Error in { : task 1 failed - "multi-argument returns are not permitted"
```

But you can make a list of your vectors, and return the value

```
foreach(I=1:8, .combine=rbind) %dopar% {  v1 <- "ant"
                                          v2 <- "pant"
                                          return(list(v1, v2)) }

         # [,1]  [,2]  
# result.1 "ant" "pant"
# result.2 "ant" "pant"
# result.3 "ant" "pant"
# result.4 "ant" "pant"
# result.5 "ant" "pant"
# result.6 "ant" "pant"
# result.7 "ant" "pant"
# result.8 "ant" "pant"

stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I would prefer a solution that does not rely on another package and this answer would fit the bill.

Comment: Follow up on this solution - how would I access the resulting list? From the stacked lists, I would want to essentially recreate v1 by subsetting to the first column of the stacked list.

Comment: EDIT: I was able to subset by assigning the whole foreach to a variable. THanks for your help!

Answer (score 5):

**Solution using [`future`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/future/versions/1.6.1):**
`doFuture` is `future`'s wrapper for `foreach` which I prefer instead of `parallel`.
Here we create `data.frame` `res` and you can access vector using `res$vector1`

```
library(doFuture)
registerDoFuture()
plan(multiprocess)

Nlength <- 1000
Nvector <- 3

res <- foreach(i = 1:Nvector, .combine = cbind) %dopar% {
    1:Nlength / pi * rnorm(1)
}
res <- data.frame(res)
colnames(res) <- paste0("vector", 1:Nvector)

dim(res)
[1] 1000    3
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I'll give it a try.