# Foreach save multiple classes of data R

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach, doparallel

I want to save multiple classes in a list within a foreach loop in `R`. I have a reproducible example here.

```
cl <- makeCluster(4)
registerDoParallel( cl)
start_time <- Sys.time()

acomb <- function(...) abind(..., along=3)
results <-foreach(i = 
1:10,.combine="acomb",.multicombine=TRUE,
  .packages=c('doParallel','foreach','base','abind')) %dopar% {
a = array(data=sample(rnorm(100000, mean=i, sd=1),9000),dim=c(3,3,1000))
aperm(a,c(2,1,3))
}
stopCluster(cl)
end_time <- Sys.time()
end_time - start_time
```

This gives me an output of `3*3*10000 array`.

I got the result as an array which is fine, however, I want their sum and mean of each as well stored as a vector in a list. The final result should be something like this:

`list(data=results,mean=mean,sum=sum)`.

Where data should be `3*3*10000`, mean should be a vector of `10000` elements and sum should also be a vector of `10000` elements. I want this to be with in foreach loop.

I also searched it a bit and found [saving multiple outputs in foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791609/saving-multiple-outputs-of-foreach-dopar-loop). However, I could not modify it to what I need here.

Comment: Return a list and change the way you combine.

Comment: @ F.Prive Could you be bit precise where I should change the code?

Answer (score 1):

Return a list in foreach and don't combine directly:

```
results2 <- foreach(i = 1:10, .packages=c('doParallel','foreach','base','abind')) %dopar% {
                    a = array(data=sample(rnorm(100000, mean=i, sd=1),9000),dim=c(3,3,1000))
                    res <- aperm(a,c(2,1,3))
                    sum <- apply(res, 3, sum)
                    list(data = res, sum = sum, mean = sum / prod(dim(res)[-3]))
                  }
```

Then, combine:

```
library(purrr)
final <- list(data = do.call(acomb, map(results2, "data")), 
              sum  = do.call(c, map(results2, "sum")), 
              mean = do.call(c, map(results2, "mean")))
```

Comment: This is what I wanted. Is it the most efficient way to this? The first part is parallel and the 2nd part is not I guess. It seems like extra step for the data processing. Thanks

Comment: This should be efficient.