# different results using %dopar% and %do%

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am trying to use `%dopar%` to speed up my `for` loop by parallelizing over multiple cores. However, I am unable to store the values that are returned. Here is a small reproducible example.

**Using %dopar%**

```
cl <- parallel::makeForkCluster(4)
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)
junk_parallel = seq(0,100000,1)
system.time(foreach(i=seq(0,10000,1))%dopar%{
  junk_parallel[i] = sqrt(i)})
stopCluster(cl)
```

Output:

```
user  system elapsed 
  2.536   0.148   2.690 
> junk_parallel[9]
[1] 8
```

**Using %do%**

```
cl <- parallel::makeForkCluster(4)
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)
junk_parallel = seq(0,100000,1)
system.time(foreach(i=seq(0,10000,1))%do%{
  junk_parallel[i] = sqrt(i)}) 
stopcluster(cl)
```

Output:

```
 user  system elapsed 
  2.172   0.004   2.174 
> junk_parallel[9]
[1] 3
```

Why is that %dopar% unable to assign the right value? When to use %dopar% vs %do%?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Obviously you haven't read the introductory vignettes. You should read them: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/foreach.pdf and https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doParallel/vignettes/gettingstartedParallel.pdf

Comment: @Roland: I have read it and could not find an answer in the vignette.  For the sake of posterity, another detailed answer on how to store values using %dopar% is  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791609/saving-multiple-outputs-of-foreach-dopar-loop

Comment: You may have read, but you didn't understand. These vignettes don't show any loops with side effects (like assignment into objects outside the loop). `foreach` is much more similar to `lapply` than to a `for` loop.

Comment: @Roland: Thanks, I will keep in mind..

Comment: You can have a look at https://privefl.github.io/blog/a-guide-to-parallelism-in-r/ to learn more about foreach and common issues with it (including yours).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The computation in a parallel loop is in it's own instance.  You're trying to assign to a global that foreach does not have access to.  Try this:

```
cl <- parallel::makeForkCluster(4)
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)
junk_parallel <- foreach(i=seq(0,10000,1)) %dopar% {
  sqrt(i)}
stopCluster(cl)
```